# Ruby - overriding/enabling multiple assignment (e.g. `a, b, c = d, e, f`)

Tags: ruby

In ruby, you can do this:

```
d = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c = d
```

`a`, `b`, and `c`, will receive the values 1, 2, and 3, respectively.

`d`, in this case in an `Array` and ruby knows to assign it's contents to `a`, `b`, and `c`. But, if `d` were a `Fixnum`, for example, only `a` would be assigned to the value of `d` while `b` and `c` would be assigned `nil`.

What properties of `d` allow it to be used for multiple assignment? In my exploring so far, I've only been able to make instances of subclasses of `Array` behave in this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a very undocumented feature, and I'd use it with caution, but here we go. From the book The Ruby Programming Language:

> When there are multiple lvalues and
>   only a single rvalue, Ruby attempts to
>   expand the rvalue into a list of
>   values to assign. If the value is an
>   array, Ruby expands the array so that
>   each element becomes its own rvalue.
>   If the value is not an array but
>   implements a `to_ary` method, Ruby
>   invokes that method and then expands
>   the array it returns.

In Ruby 1.8 it is the `to_ary` method, <strike>in Ruby 1.9 documentation says it calls `to_splat`, but I haven't tested (no 1.9 in this machine)</strike><sub>It didn't work as expected</sub>. So, you have to define a `to_ary` method in your object.

```
class Week
  def to_ary
    %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
  end
end

mon, tue, wed, thu, *weekend = Week.new
```

* `%w(...)` Is a special notation for an array of words, if you are lazy to write `['monday', 'tuesday' ...]`

Comment: I think Try Ruby! uses 1.9 . Or you can totally drop that and use <s>jQuery</s> RVM.

Comment: :) Actually went to `rvm install 1.9.1` after the answer

Answer (score 7):

> What properties of `d` allow it to be used for multiple assignment?

`d` has to be an `Array` or be convertible to one. IOW it must be either an instance of the `Array` class (or any of its subclasses) or respond to the `to_ary` message:

```
def (not_an_array = Object.new).to_ary; [:foo, :bar, :baz] end

foo, bar, baz = not_an_array

foo # => :foo
bar # => :bar
baz # => :baz
```

Note that this is an instance of a more general pattern in Ruby: almost all methods in Ruby that expect an `Array`, a `String`, an `Integer` or a `Float` will also accept an object that responds to `to_ary`, `to_str`, `to_int` or `to_float`. And your *own* methods should, too, by the way!